# IP Blocking URLs on Apache

Tags: php, security, apache, cakephp

I need to block access to my entire site via IP Address except the url /api which should be open to all.

I am currently using ...

```
<LocationMatch /admin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from [MY IP]
</LocationMatch>
```

this blocks access urls starting with /admin. But I want to block all urls except the ones that start /api.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On # (only needs to happen once in .htaccess files.

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.103\.18\.104     # <--YOUR IP HERE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api    # page or directory to ignore                   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/no_access.html [R=401] # where to send blocked requests
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. I get an error 401 Authentication required.

Comment: Rewrite requires the use of additional module. would still be better to use core.

Comment: @Chris - the code I supplied returns a 401 to the browser if your IP does not match. 
@Mauris - that is true. But not all users have access to the core config file. and rewrite works at a directory level

Compromise?
Use location to lock down entire site (replace '/admin' with '/')
Use additional location block to unlock /api (reverse deny,allow to allow all)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can first block the whole site, then simply allow /api.

```
<LocationMatch />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from [MY IP]
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch /api>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

Sorry I couldn't test it due to the way XAMPP is configured on my PC. Pray it works.

Comment: Did you try switching the order of the rules?